# In Roscpp, can I access parameters from different nodes?

Tags: ros, c++, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Example: I have always the same node type, lets say with a parameter named "shape"

I make one node (node A) with shape = "square"

I make a second node (node B) with shape = "circle"

in the console if i did rosparam list i would see
/nodeA/shape
/nodeB/shape

and if i did rosparam get /nodeA/shape i would see "Square", but is it possible in my test file, my cpp file, to use some form of get parameter when creating a node, so that I can see that node A shape is "Square"?
pseudocode:

```
    if(&newNode/shape == &nodeA/shape)
              kill(newNode, SIGINT)
```

Overall, i want to be able to test and see if a value of the parameter exists, and then if it exists, i will do a kill(pid, SIGINT).

But i am having a hard time accessing the parameter value of the other nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212057/in-roscpp,-can-i-access-parameters-from-different-nodes?/) by [thailor3](https://answers.ros.org/users/22915/thailor3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROScpp provides a [getParam()](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server) interface on the nodeHandle. It accepts "global" (fully qualified) names beginning with a `/`, as well as "private" names relative to that node.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thailor3](https://answers.ros.org/users/22915/thailor3/) on 2015-06-25**:
so in order to get any node's param on the rosparam server, then i can do getParam()? for instance if i have the list of params:
/image1/cam1/1
/image1/cam1/2
/image2/cam2/1
/image2/cam2/2

and i am launching another node that will spawn the paramters /image3/cam3/1, i do getParam("/image1/cam1/1")?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-06-26**:
Correct! Every node has access to the gull parameter server. You just have to get the names correct.